# Tag Gold Badges have reset the awarded date to yesterday

Tags: bug, tags, badges, dupehammer

I got notifications yesterday that I had earned gold tag badges on scifi stack exchange which was odd because I earned those badges years ago and was actually the first person to have those.

**Notification**:

[image]

**Badge 1**: [image]

**Badge 2**: [image]

Here's [one of the questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223923/who-was-the-lord-of-dragonstone) I closed as duplicate about a year ago with my gold tag badge privileges.

Comment: I'm working on a fix to reset the award date

Comment: @Taryn Goodluck, looking forward to see it resolved :)